# using sql in excel vba using ADODB

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the sql queries as followed to select the data in a excel file, what I use in the clause is "from table1", but actually I just give the name randomly and I dont know how it create the alias for the workbook.

```
cn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=C:\workbook.xlsx; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;"";")
rst.Open "SELECT *" _

              & "from table1;", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

for the first time it runs well to get link to the workbook and the correct result.  but when I try to select another workbook in the same path using the same clause"from table1" it gives the run time error as following:

[image]

so I changed it to table2 but the same : cant find the object.

Is there anyone can help me and explain the function? Do not hesitate if you need other information.

Many thanks,

Jiamin

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Please paste your code as text. You can highlight it after you paste it and hit the `{}` button in the editor to preserve line feeds and whitesapce.

Comment: As for the error it means that there is table named "Table1" in your second workbook. I'm guessing by the name that your first workbook has a table in it and it is named "Table1". You ***may*** have some luck using something like `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1]` instead of guessing at table names.

Comment: Unless you're using Paint to edit your code, the code is text and should be copied and pasted as text into your question here. Images of code are useless. Please [edit] your question to do so. The error can also be entered as text, which means it is searchable. Images are not.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question for the text of the code, I'm new here and thanks for all your reminds.

Jiamin

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JNevill,

I've modified the code as following:

```
cn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=C:\workbook.xlsx; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;"";")

   rst.Open "SELECT *" _

               & "from [Sheet0$];", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

and it works now, Thanks for your response and have a nice day.

Jiamin